# extract millions of records from sql server and load into oracle database using python script

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, oracle, batch-processing

I am extracting millions of data from sql server and inserting into oracle db using python. It is taking 1 record to insert in oracle table in 1 sec.. takes hours to insert. What is the fastest approach to load ?
My code below:

```
def insert_data(conn,cursor,query,data,batch_size = 10000):
    recs = []
    count = 1
    for rec in data:
        recs.append(rec)
        if count % batch_size == 0:

            cursor.executemany(query, recs,batcherrors=True)
            conn.commit()`enter code here`
            recs = []
        count = count +1
        cursor.executemany(query, recs,batcherrors=True)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: The faster approach is to use any industrial ETL-tool,like SQL Server Integration Services, Informatica PowerCentre etc.

Comment: An RBAR process is *always* going to be (significantly) slower than one that operates in sets and copies the data over in Bulk Operations.

Comment: unfortunately do not have the priviledge to use any industrial tool. so have to use python

Comment: then you might wanna use `pandas` or `pyspark` or other big data frameworks available on python

Comment: can you give an example how to use pandas?

Comment: SQL Server cames with SSIS which is one of the best ETL... Why don't you use it ? It seems clear that if you want speed you need to take appropriate tools. Otherwise there is no point in asking questions like this!

Comment: @SQLpro said " SSIS which is one of the best ETL.".  That's a laugh.  See my proposed answer, where I also explained how a pl/sql procedure in the oracle database outperformed SSIS by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Can you split the 1 million rows into 10 different data set and call the Python procedure in parallel? you can use multiprocessing, i have done it when loading 10 million rows which was taking 2 hours, and using multiprocessing it finishes in 20 minutes.

Comment: Is it slow because your fetching operation is slow?  Or is it that the data insert is slow?  For the actual data insert in Python to Oracle DB, then using executeMany() bulk insert is as good as it gets.  Adding pandas won't help the insert, since that (should) eventually call cx_Oracle executeMany().

Comment: data insert is slow.. is python not the right/effective platform to transfer huge data?

Comment: It's all about disk and network I/O.   And whether you need to transform the data.  And what bits of your system has access to net or disk or DBs.  The Gateway solution has merits.  If you have to write to disk for some reason, the look at using SQL Loader or External Tables.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you cannot buy a 3d Party ETL tool, but you can certainly write a procedure in PL/SQL in the oracle database.

First, install the oracle Transparenet Gateway for ODBC.  No license cost involved.
Second, in the oracl db, create a db link to reference the MSSQL database via the gateway.
Third, write a PL/SQL procedure to pull the data from the MSSQL database, via the db link.

I was once presented a problem similar to yours.  developer was using SSIS to copy around a million rows from mssql to oracle.  Taking over 4 hours.  I ran a trace on his process and saw that it was copying row-by-row, slow-by-slow.  Took me less than 30 minutes write a pl/sql proc to copy the data, and it completed in less than 4 minutes.

I give a high-level view of the entire setup and process, [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/):

EDIT:
Thought you might like to see exactly how simple the actual procedure is:

```
create or replace my_load_proc
begin
  insert into my_oracle_table (col_a,
                               col_b,
                               col_c)
  select sql_col_a,
          sql_col_b,
          sql_col_c
  from mssql_tbl@mssql_link;

end;
```

My actual procedure has more to it, dealing with run-time logging, emailing notification of completion, etc.  But the above is the 'guts' of it, pulling the data from mssql into oracle.

Comment: thank you for your useful point,would you please guide how to define "mssql_link"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

then you might wanna use pandas or pyspark or other big data frameworks available on python
there are  a lot of example out there, here is how to load data from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-pandas?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

server = 'servername' 
database = 'AdventureWorks' 
username = 'yourusername' 
password = 'databasename'  
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = "SELECT [CountryRegionCode], [Name] FROM Person.CountryRegion;"
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)


# you do data manipulation that is needed here
# then insert data into oracle


conn = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://xxxxxx')

df.to_sql(table_name, conn, index=False, if_exists="replace")
```

something like that, ( that might not work 100% , but just to give you an idea how you can do it)