# what is the best way to migrate data from SQL Server to Oracle database

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, oracle, etl, oracle19c

I have two remote databases, Oracle 19c and SQL Server 19. In my redhat linux, I have to read SQL Server table and write it to Oracle.
I wrote a Python code to read data from SQL Server and insert it to Oracle database. But, I think it is so slow. Since, the table has about 16 million records.
I search a lot and see this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66550879/6640504

It said that **Oracle Transparent Gateway** makes it possible to run a procedure for migrating data from extra database to Oracle in little time.
I can access to Oracle database using terminal and don't have any graphical accesses.

Would you please guide me if **Oracle Transparent Gateway** is the best way to migrate data from SQL Server to Oracle database, how to install **Oracle Transparent Gateway** and use it? If not, what is the best way?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Best way is an opinion-based. You can also try any suitable ETL-tool, e.g. SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), Informatica etc

Comment: @Sergey I said I don't have any graphical accesses.

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle are on the same server?

Comment: No, they are on the separate systems.

Comment: Then you can install SSIS on the Windows machine and transfer data between them. Another option is linked-server(SQL Server) or DB-Link (Oracle), but these technologies sometimes work extremely strange

Comment: @Sergey, thank you for your suggestions. But, I don't access to the SQL Server system, I just have a URL to connect to its Schema.

Comment: Then start talking to the teams that manage these two systems as well as the person (your team?) who has given you this task. As already mentioned, it is pointless to ask any question about "best" because it is highly dependent on your circumstances and it simply cannot be measured. No one but you knows if this is a ETL task (one-time or continuing) or a replication task. You have some serious restrictions that you mention only when questioned.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to work from SQL Developer.
You can download SQL Developer for free from https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html
SQL Developer provides a "migration workbench" that supports SQL Server.
The data migration can be done online or offline.
Online causes the table data to be moved by SQL Developer when you have completed the necessary information in the wizard; Offline causes SQL Developer to generate scripts after you have completed the necessary information in the wizard, and you must later run those scripts if you want to move the data. (Online moves are convenient for moving small data sets; offline moves are useful for moving large volumes of data.)

Answer (score 0):

the best approach to export the data in json.

then import that json to oracle database. Most of the approach I worked on it's going to take time.